# Rails create map to existing object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following model:

```
class Post
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :post_tags
end

class Tag
  has_many :post_tags
  has_many :posts, :through => :post_tags

  validate_uniqueness_of :name
end

class PostTag
  validate_uniqness_of :post_id, :scope => :tag_id
end
```

Now if i want to crate a new tag that doesn't exsist I can use

```
Post.find_by_id(X).tags.create(:name => "foo")
```

But if the tag already esists, that will say TagExsits, but no entry in the map-table post_tags will be created.

How to do, that if the tag exists, only a map will be created?

Comment: you mean like `Post.find_by_id(X).tags.where(:name => "foo").first_or_create`? That'll create a new tag if it doesn't exist, and otherwise will return it.

Comment: If Tag exists, only an Entry in the post_tags table should be created

Comment: Did you try: `Post.find_by_id(X).post_tags.create(:tag_id => Tag.find_or_create_name("foo").id)` ?